# Derivative of x repeatedly divide by 1 +x at x=0?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$y=\frac x{1+\frac x{1+\frac x{1+\ldots}}}$$

Evaluate $\frac{dy}{dx}\big\vert_{x=0}$

Comment: $y=\frac{x}{1+y}$. Of course you have to prove this relation ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming such a $y$ exists, we have $$y=\frac x{1+y}$$$$y+y^2=x$$$$\frac{dy}{dx}+2y\frac{dy}{dx}=1$$$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac1{1+2y}$$Assuming $2y+1\neq0$.

Comment: $y$ exists ! Sequences will get you which function this is . You have to work with sequences because you cannot simply replace a part of the fraction .... of course we don’t know the op’s knowledge  so let’s stick to intuition , right ?

Comment: What might be the value of $y$ for $x=-1$, now ?... or in fact for any $x \lt - \frac{1}{4}$ ?

Comment: The continued fraction has domain $x\geq 0$. You have to take care of the domain first , then do that sequence thing.

Comment: @Tolaso Not quite. As hinted by lmsteffan, it only fails to converge for $x<-1/4$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Yep, you are right. My mistake.